# Java leer y escribir fichero

Tags: java, try-catch

Buenas compañeros.
Tengo unos problemas con un programa que quiero hacer en java que, a partir de un fichero *doc.txt* creado previamente, pregunte al usuario una palabra para buscar en el contenido del archivo y genero uno nuevo *resultado.txt* que tenga el texto del archivo *doc.txt* pero con la palabra buscada con mayúsculas , el numero de palabras de cada linea de archivo y el numero de palabras total. adjunto el código.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LecturaFitxer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Fichero que queremos leer
        File f = new File("C:\\prueba\\Documento.txt");
        Scanner lector = null;
        File k = new File("C:\\prueba\\Resultado.txt");
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

        try {
            System.out.print("Escribe la palabra que quieres buscar?");
            String palabra=r.next();
            // Leemos el contenido del fichero
            System.out.println("Leyendo el contenido fichero...");
            lector = new Scanner(f);
            //escribimos datos con esto
            PrintStream escriptor = new PrintStream(k);

            // Leemos la linia de cada fichero
            while (lector.hasNextLine()) {



         String linia = lector.nextLine();     // Guardamos la linia en string
                System.out.println(linia);          // Imprimimos la linia en string
            }
            lector.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Mensaje error: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: ¿Has intentado implementar algo? ¿Qué es lo que no te funciona? En tu código no veo nada relacionado con lo que estás preguntando.

Comment: es que no se como hacer para que me coja la palabra i la ponga en mayusculas , si me puedes dar algun consejo te lo agradeceria gracias

Comment: Quizás sería mejor opción si implementases el resto de cosas que si sabes hacer y cuando te encontrases con el problema de pasar el contenido a mayúsculas nos actualices el código y nos expongas el problema que te encontraste.

Answer (score 1):

para obtener la palabra concreta podrías hacer un indexOf de la cadena:

```
int index = linia.indexOf(palabra);
```

Pero ni siquiera te harái falta encontrar la posición para tu problema ya que tienes la palabra a sustituir. Para eso java te ofrece el método replace:

`public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)`

que implementarías como:

```
String toUpper = palabra.toUpperCase();
linia.replace(palabra,toUpper);
```

Answer (score 1):

usa el método toUpperCase de la clase String:

ejemplo:

```
String Str = new String("abc");
System.out.println(Str.toUpperCase());
```

devuelve:
    ABC

link de la api: 
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()